# $a^2+b^2$ is the product of two numbers one the reverse of the other

Tags: nt.number-theory

As an example:

$429^2+101^2=394\cdot 493$.
394 is the reverse of 493.

Are there infinitely many

$a^2+b^2$ which are the product of a number and his reverse?

a,b positive integers

Second question:

Are there infinitely many

$a^2+b^2$ which are the product of two composite numbers one the reverse of the other?

Obviously I asked this because it is connected with ec primes

Comment: Let $p,q$ be primes having $1\bmod4$ congruence and $q$ be reverse of $p$ (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Emirp.html). The product $pq$ has $a^2+b^2$ representation.

Comment: @LSpice what if p and q are not primes?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440062/a2b2-is-the-product-of-two-numbers-one-the-reverse-of-the-other#comment1135072_440062), then it depends quite a bit on the factorisations of $p$ and $q$.  (I deleted a comment in response to @Turbo because I missed their [requirement](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440062/a2b2-is-the-product-of-two-numbers-one-the-reverse-of-the-other#comment1135069_440062) that *both* $p$ and $q$ be $1$ modulo $4$.)

Comment: This question would likely be a better fit for math.stackexchange.com; I wouldn't put it in the domain of 'research mathematics' per se (with a few rare exceptions, questions about digital representations and digit patterns tend not to be).

Comment: One that doesn't fit the patterns mentioned so far: $15\times51=765=729+36=441+324$ ($=27^2+6^2=21^2+18^2$).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440062/a2b2-is-the-product-of-two-numbers-one-the-reverse-of-the-other#comment1135069_440062) by @Turbo:

If
\begin{gather*}
j=k^2+l^2 \\
s=m^2+n^2
\end{gather*}
then by the Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity we have
$$
sj=(km+ln)^2+(km-ln)^2.
$$
Therefore, if $s$ and $j$ are reverse pairs of this form, their product has the desired property.

It is very easy to construct infinitely many numbers $j$, $s$ of this form, for example there are infinitely many pairs which have only two non-zero digits, i.e. $s=u^2 \cdot 10^{2v}+w^2$ and $j=w^2 \cdot 10^{2v}+u^2$ for distinct non-zero digits $u$, $w$.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require the two composite numbers to be distinct, try the square of any palindrome starting and ending in $5$.